# Problema con pyinstaller

Tags: python

He intentado hacer un ejecutable a partir de un programa en python. He instalado correctamente pyintaller, sin embargo, a la hora de ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

"pyinstaller" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Cabe decir que estoy usando la ruta donde tengo el archivo .py como se indica en otros foros, y que he visualizado mediante pip list que pyinstaller esta correctamente instalando.

Seria de gran ayuda si alguien me dijera cual puede ser el fallo. Gracias

Comment: Tienes mal configurada las variables de entorno, en el sistema o en virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

En la consola ejecuta el script de activado:

- En Anaconda: `<ruta de anaconda3>\Scripts\activate.bat`
- En Python: Tienes que hacer tu [el entorno](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) con [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) y luego lo de activar

Pero si solo te interesa gastar el pyinstaller y solo tienes una version de python instalada puedes ponerle directamente la carpeta de `<ruta de python>\Scripts` a `PATH` (pyinstaller es un exe tambien)

Cuando instalas python añades la ruta de donde esta `python.exe` pero la consola no sabe que cosas tiene ese python (puedes tener varios), el bat le da el "contexto" a la consola (pero los editores si puede buscar y diferenciar y cuando abres una consola en un proyecto te la abren con el entorno)

Comment: No me reconoce el comando \activate.bat, de hecho no cuento con la carpeta Scripts...

Comment: Ya cambie el post, algo que talvez te pueda fallar a parte de eso es que lo instales y no este el exe, y a eso solo lo desinstalas y vuelves a instalarlo con `python -m pip install  --no-cache-dir pyinstaller`; Tienes que tener si o si la carpeta `Scripts`, sino no podrías usar pip

Answer (score 0):

Esto si se arregla configurando correctamente las variables de entorno. En mi caso estaba poniendo mal la ruta, puedes usar esta y cambiarla segun tu versión de python:

```
%AppData%\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

También puedes conocer donde se instalan las librerias reinstalando alguna que ya tengas, ahí en consola te muestra las rutas de instalación.